# Getting "Wrong number of arguments" after DotNet-Update in ActiveX written with C#

Tags: c#, com, activex

I developed two ActiveX-Controls with C# and both work fine. Until Windows installs an update to the DotNet-Framework. Each time that happens we have to run regasm again and everything is fine again. At first the exception was "Member not found". Then I added an Interface that defines all public Methods and Properties. Since than the exception changed to "Wrong number of arguments". Even on methods that don't even have arguments.

The Control is defined with this attributes:

```
[ProgId("MyCtrlNameSpace.MemoControl")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMemoControlEventSink),typeof(IMemoControl))]
[Guid("091085F7-DE1E-4E2C-8A1A-1AE975416281")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class MemoControl : UserControl
{...}
```

The first Interface defines the Events:

```
[Guid("36813D5C-295F-4222-A3FC-D0372BAA2893")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMemoControlEventSink: IMemoControl
{
[DispId(1)]
void ControlZoomed(object sender, object e);
}
```

The second Interface defines the Methods and Properties

```
[Guid("D119B336-DA87-47BA-B21D-306FB6037008")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMemoControl
{
[DispId(100)]
int CustomContextMenuItemCount { get; }
}
```

Everything is compiled as x86, cause the unmanaged application that uses my control is a x86 application. At first it was AnyCpu, till I found a post, where the AnyCpu was the problem.

I have a virtual machine where I can reproduce it. Install my controls => everything works fine => install DotNet-Framework-Update => Exception => regasm /codebase /tlb => everything works fine. I want a solution where I dont have to track if an update was installed an reregister the controls after that.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Did you remember to do a clean build?

Comment: "Member not found" or "Wrong number of arguments" are usually the sign of two versions installed and whoever picks one picks the wrong one. Different that "class not registered" for example.

Comment: @jdweng: Yes, our buildscript makes it automaticly for all components. thx. for your help

Comment: @Simon Mourier: nope, both controls are definetly only in one version installed. at least mine. one of them is just a normal button in a usercontrol. all controls are versioned in 1.0.0.0 and no version updates on the build. thx. for your help

Comment: These errors demonstrate a discrepancy between expectation and result. Versioning, tlb and binary not in sync, etc.

Comment: @Simon Mourier any idea how i can fix it or why running regasm fixes it?

Comment: Actually no :-) I'm pretty sure it's a "versioning" issue but I can't see why a framework update would kill your registration. Regasm only does simple modifications to the registry. Note you don't need /tlb to register your code, only to create a tlb (during dev phase)